# Looking for type-casting rules in JS

Tags: javascript, casting

I'm looking for a concrete set of rules as to what gets automatically typecast and when.  I'm trying to come up with some guidelines for newer devs, e.g. it just came up that:

```
90 > '100'   // int compare
'90' > 100   // int compare
'90' > '100' // string compare
```

And the only answer I could come up with as to why is "because" :)

Comment: It would be interesting to know the rules, but my guidelines would be to always be explicit.  If you want a string to be treated like an int, make it one.  If for no other reason than readability.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `'026' < 24` may return true in some browsers because the string is treated as an octal number (in this case 22).

Ideally you want to always type-cast manually. Either with `a = ''+a` to cast to string, or `a = parseInt(a,10);` to cast to integer.

That should be the explanation, rather than trying to explain automatic typecasting

Comment: Also `a^0` or `a*1` may be used if you doing stuff for [js1k](http://js1k.com/) ;)

Comment: @JuicyScripter why not just `+a`?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to understand what's happening, then you should read the spec:

- http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3

A note on the [conventions in that section](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-5.2):

> Type(x) is used as shorthand for "the type of x"